# I want to show my data in div from database without reloading the page. How I can do this?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using a div tag as a container of data, a list of links are present on the page when the user clicks a link I want to show its related data from database in that div, that div will appear on link click on top of page. 
I am using asp.net C#
In detail presently i am showing data in diff-2 div tags on link clicks and all by using

```
    divid.InnerHtml="";
```

in code behind but now i want to use single single div that will appear on click of link and I want to load contents from database to be loaded in that div corresponding to the link clicked.

```
        <div id="popUpDiv"  runat="server"
        style="
            display:none;
            position:fixed;
            top:20%;
            left:20%;
            right:20%;
            min-width:60%;
            min-height:60%;
            background-color:Gray;
    z-index: 10002;">
         My popup box
         </div>
```

this is the the button which presently shows div

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPopUp" OnClientClick="togglePopUp('popUpDiv'); return false;"
             text="Pop Up a div box" runat="server" />
```

this is C# code

```
while (dr.Read())
            {
                sr = sr + "<table border=\"0px\" ><tr valign=\"top\"><td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\"><a href=\"About.aspx\">" + dr.GetString(2) + "</a></td></tr><tr><td align=\"left\">"+"<img alt=\"\" src=\"Container/Images/aus.jpg\" />"+"</td></tr><tr valign=\"top\" ><td style=\"text-align:Justify;\" valign=\"top\">" + dr.GetString(3) + "</td></tr></table>";
            }
            con.Close();
            dr.Close();
            popUpDiv.InnerHtml = sr;
```

and this is my javascript to display div

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function togglePopUp(div_id) {
        var el = document.getElementById(div_id);
        if (el.style.display == 'block') { el.style.display = 'none'; }
        else { el.style.display = 'block'; }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: My guess is you should use Ajax, try searching on google for some basic tutorial. That should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses ajax and the end request handler to show the div, add this to your aspx page.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
 Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandle);
 function endRequestHandle(sender, Args) {
        if (pbControl.name.toString() == "btnPopUp") {
        var el = document.getElementById(div_id);
        if (el.style.display == 'block') { el.style.display = 'none'; }
        else { el.style.display = 'block'; }                  
        }
</script>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:Button ID="btnPopUp" text="Pop Up a div box" runat="server" />
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Codebehind:

```
while (dr.Read())
 {
   sr = sr + "<table border=\"0px\" ><tr valign=\"top\"><td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\"><a href=\"About.aspx\">" + dr.GetString(2) + "</a></td></tr><tr><td align=\"left\">"+"<img alt=\"\" src=\"Container/Images/aus.jpg\" />"+"</td></tr><tr valign=\"top\" ><td style=\"text-align:Justify;\" valign=\"top\">" + dr.GetString(3) + "</td></tr></table>";
 }
con.Close();
dr.Close();
popUpDiv.InnerHtml = sr;
```